# What datatype should be used for storing phone numbers in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I need to store phone numbers in a table. Please suggest which datatype should I use? 
**Wait. Please read on before you hit reply..**

This field needs to be indexed heavily as Sales Reps can use this field for searching (including wild character search).

As of now, we are expecting phone numbers to come in a number of formats (from an XML file). Do I have to write a parser to convert to a uniform format? There could be millions of data (with duplicates) and I dont want to tie up the server resources (in activities like preprocessing too much) every time some source data comes through..

Any suggestions are welcome..

Update: **I have no control over source data. Just that the structure of xml file is standard. Would like to keep the xml parsing to a minimum.
Once it is in database, retrieval should be quick. One crazy suggestion going on around here is that it should even work with Ajax AutoComplete feature (so Sales Reps can see the matching ones immediately). OMG!!**

Comment: You might want to use https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber for parsing / cleanup of the source data.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Does this include:

- International numbers?
- Extensions?
- Other information besides the actual number (like "ask for bobby")?

If all of these are no, I would use a 10 char field and strip out all non-numeric data. If the first is a yes and the other two are no, I'd use two varchar(50) fields, one for the original input and one with all non-numeric data striped and used for indexing. If 2 or 3 are yes, I think I'd do two fields and some kind of crazy parser to determine what is extension or other data and deal with it appropriately. Of course you could avoid the 2nd column by doing something with the index where it strips out the extra characters when creating the index, but I'd just make a second column and probably do the stripping of characters with a trigger.

Update: to address the AJAX issue, it may not be as bad as you think. If this is realistically the main way anything is done to the table, store only the digits in a secondary column as I said, and then make the index for that column the clustered one.

Comment: Yes to all questions. I have no control on the source data. Some good suggestions there. Thanks.

Comment: Am nit-picking, but a 10 char field would not cover most UK mobile numbers and many UK land line numbers. Would allow more than 10 even in US to allow for future scaling of phone numbers.

Comment: Why not `decimal(10,0)` instead of `char`?

Comment: @MrAnderson, I think that's because with `decimal(10,0)` you have to pad leading zeroes back onto the number whenever you need it..

Comment: Depending where you are in the world, I [don't think 10 characters is long enough](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbering_plan), as also highlighted by Brad's answer.

Comment: Extensions & ask for bobby means?

Answer (score 57):

We use varchar(15) and certainly index on that field.

The reason being is that International standards can support up to 15 digits

[Wikipedia - Telephone Number Formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_number)

If you do support International numbers, I recommend the separate storage of a World Zone Code or Country Code to better filter queries by so that you do not find yourself parsing and checking the length of your phone number fields to limit the returned calls to USA for example

Comment: I may be overlooking something obvious, but what benefit is there in using a character data type to store numeric data?  And if you're storing more than numeric data (e.g. the delimiters), then wouldn't you need more than 15 characters to store a formatted 15-digit number?

Comment: @drrcknlsn the reason is the leading zero - some (most in some countries) start with a zero

Comment: @drrcknlsn I know this comment is 2 years old, but in the event that anyone comes across your comment: Usually the rule of thumb is that integer data types should be used to store numeric data that makes sense to do math on, and the rest are strings. For example, adding two telephone numbers, or multiplying SIN/SSN numbers doesn't make sense, so they should be stored as strings.

Comment: @drrcknlsn why not `decimal(10,0)` then instead of `char`?

Comment: @Mr A : Maybe because the length of the phone number may vary from one region/country to another. Infilling with leading zeros would then create an additional parsing problem.

Answer (score 5):

Use CHAR(10) if you are storing US Phone numbers only. Remove everything but the digits.

Answer (score 3):

I'm probably missing the obvious here, but wouldn't a varchar just long enough for your longest expected phone number work well?

If I *am* missing something obvious, I'd love it if someone would point it out...

Answer (score 3):

I would use a varchar(22). Big enough to hold a north american phone number with extension. You would want to strip out all the nasty '(', ')', '-' characters, or just parse them all into one uniform format.

Alex

Answer (score 2):

nvarchar with preprocessing to standardize them as much as possible. You'll probably want to extract extensions and store them in another field.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server 2005 is pretty well optimized for substring queries for text in indexed varchar fields. For 2005 they introduced new statistics to the string summary for index fields. This helps significantly with full text searching.

Answer (score 2):

using varchar is pretty inefficient. use the money type and create a user declared type "phonenumber" out of it, and create a rule to only allow positive numbers.

if you declare it as (19,4) you can even store a 4 digit extension and be big enough for international numbers, and only takes 9 bytes of storage. Also, indexes are speedy.

Comment: Grats. -1. Ingorance and not reading - waht abuot %233% - full table scan + conversions? This is a standard problem and there is a standard solution and it is NOT number. Which strips out all formatting, btw.

Comment: @TomTom While I agree `money` is not the answer, if searching by substring is not required (and I'd imagine many don't need to look up a record based on just part of a phone number), what would be wrong with using `decimal(10,0)`?

Answer (score 1):

Normalise the data then store as a varchar.  Normalising could be tricky.

That should be a one-time hit.  Then as a new record comes in, you're comparing it to normalised data.  Should be very fast.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `varchar` field with a length restriction.

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to accommodate many different phone number formats (and probably include things like extensions etc.) it may make the most sense to just treat it as you would any other varchar. If you could control the input, you could take a number of approaches to make the data more useful, but it doesn't sound that way.

Once you decide to simply treat it as any other string, you can focus on overcoming the inevitable issues regarding bad data, mysterious phone number formating and whatever else will pop up. The challenge will be in building a good search strategy for the data and not how you store it in my opinion. It's always a difficult task having to deal with a large pile of data which you had no control over collecting.

Answer (score 1):

Use SSIS to extract and process the information. That way you will have the processing of the XML files separated from SQL Server. You can also do the SSIS transformations on a separate server if needed. Store the phone numbers in a standard format using VARCHAR. NVARCHAR would be unnecessary since we are talking about numbers and maybe a couple of other chars, like '+', ' ', '(', ')' and '-'.

Answer (score 1):

It is fairly common to use an "x" or "ext" to indicate extensions, so allow 15 characters (for full international support) plus 3 (for "ext") plus 4 (for the extension itself) giving a total of 22 characters. That should keep you safe.

Alternatively, normalise on input so any "ext" gets translated to "x", giving a maximum of 20.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this thread is old, but it's worth mentioning an advantage of storing as a numeric type for formatting purposes, specifically in .NET framework.

IE

```
.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "(###)###-####" // Will not work on a string
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75105/what-datatype-should-be-used-for-storing-phone-numbers-in-sql-server-2005#comment109423789_61000613

Answer (score 1):

**It is always better to have separate tables for multi valued attributes like phone number.**

As you have no control on source data so, you can parse the data from XML file and convert it into the proper format so that there will not be any issue with formats of a particular country and store it in a separate table so that **indexing and retrieval both will be efficient**.

Thank you.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question fully.

Answer (score 0):

Use data type long instead.. dont use int because it only allows whole numbers between -32,768 and 32,767 but if you use long data type you can insert numbers between -2,147,483,648 and 2,147,483,647.

Comment: This is fine, but you cant store international numbers with country code as some numbers begin with country code.Eg :  0094777123123, Better use a varchar(15) field with  some regex validation.

Answer (score 0):

For most cases, it will be done with **bigint**

Just save unformatted phone numbers like: 19876543210, 02125551212, etc.

Check the topic about [bigint vs varchar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15241708/mysql-bigint-vs-varchar)