# what could be a suitable datatype for storing telephone numbers in sql server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What datatype should be used for storing phone numbers in SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75105/what-datatype-should-be-used-for-storing-phone-numbers-in-sql-server-2005)

There are various datatypes from which i can choose for example varchar or bigint or decimal or money but which one could be the best in all respect.

Comment: you have some perfectly good answers given on your previous questions but have not marked any of them as the answer. You should go back and look at them.

Comment: sorry that's my fault anyway thanks

Answer (score 0):

VARCHAR - a telephone number is a highly geographically-specific data item, and may typically contain brackets, hyphens, or letters as well as numeric digits.