# How do format a phone number as a String in Java?

Tags: java, string, number-formatting

I have been storing phone numbers as longs and I would like to simply add hyphens when printing the phone number as a string.

I tried using `DecimalFormat` but that doesn't like the hyphen. Probably because it is meant for formatting decimal numbers and not longs.

```
long phoneFmt = 123456789L;
DecimalFormat phoneFmt = new DecimalFormat("###-###-####");
System.out.println(phoneFmt.format(phoneNum)); //doesn't work as I had hoped
```

Ideally, I would like to have parenthesis on the area code too.

```
new DecimalFormat("(###)-###-####");
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Storing phone numbers in a numeric type such as `long` is not a good idea. Phone numbers are really a kind of labels, not numbers that you'd want to do calculations with. What if a phone number starts with 0 - you couldn't store that in a numeric type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how I ended up doing it:

```
private String printPhone(Long phoneNum) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(15);
    StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder(phoneNum.toString());

    while (temp.length() < 10)
        temp.insert(0, "0");

    char[] chars = temp.toString().toCharArray();

    sb.append("(");
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        if (i == 3)
            sb.append(") ");
        else if (i == 6)
            sb.append("-");
        sb.append(chars[i]);
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

I understand that this does not support international numbers, but I'm not writing a "real" application so I'm not concerned about that. I only accept a 10 character long as a phone number. I just wanted to print it with some formatting.

Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 53):

You can use [String.replaceFirst](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) with regex method like

```
    long phoneNum = 123456789L;
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(phoneNum).replaceFirst("(\\d{3})(\\d{3})(\\d+)", "($1)-$2-$3"));
```

Comment: I used this to generate random ID numbers that follow a specific format. Thanks.

Comment: Regex is fine, but in a tight loop, this will be very slow.

Answer (score 26):

To get your desired output:

```
long phoneFmt = 123456789L;
//get a 12 digits String, filling with left '0' (on the prefix)   
DecimalFormat phoneDecimalFmt = new DecimalFormat("0000000000");
String phoneRawString= phoneDecimalFmt.format(phoneFmt);

java.text.MessageFormat phoneMsgFmt=new java.text.MessageFormat("({0})-{1}-{2}");
    //suposing a grouping of 3-3-4
String[] phoneNumArr={phoneRawString.substring(0, 3),
          phoneRawString.substring(3,6),
          phoneRawString.substring(6)};

System.out.println(phoneMsgFmt.format(phoneNumArr));
```

The result at the Console looks like this:

> (012)-345-6789

For storing phone numbers, you should consider [using a data type other than numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75105/what-datatype-should-be-used-for-storing-phone-numbers-in-sql-server-2005).

Answer (score 20):

The easiest way to do this is by using the built in MaskFormatter in the [javax.swing.text library](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/MaskFormatter.html).

You can do something like this :

```
import javax.swing.text.MaskFormatter;

String phoneMask= "###-###-####";
String phoneNumber= "123423452345";

MaskFormatter maskFormatter= new MaskFormatter(phoneMask);
maskFormatter.setValueContainsLiteralCharacters(false);
maskFormatter.valueToString(phoneNumber) ;
```

Comment: Very easy if you combine it with a DecimalFormat. The MaskFormatter's checked ParseException is annoying though.

Comment: Works nice. I made it an utility method.

Answer (score 9):

If you really need the right way then you can use Google's recently open sourced [libphonenumber](http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/)

Comment: I don't think another library is necessary. There must be an easy way to do it with all the different Java formatting APIs. I just don't know which one to use.

Comment: @styfle: formatting alone is not your problem, storing a phonenumber in a `long` is.

Answer (score 9):

You could also use https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber. Here is an example:

```
import com.google.i18n.phonenumbers.NumberParseException;
import com.google.i18n.phonenumbers.PhoneNumberUtil;
import com.google.i18n.phonenumbers.Phonenumber;

String s = "18005551234";
PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
Phonenumber.PhoneNumber phoneNumber = phoneUtil.parse(s, Locale.US.getCountry());
String formatted = phoneUtil.format(phoneNumber, PhoneNumberUtil.PhoneNumberFormat.NATIONAL);
```

Here you can get the library on your classpath: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.libphonenumber/libphonenumber

Answer (score 6):

The worst possible solution would be:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
long tmp = phoneFmt;
sb.append("(");
sb.append(tmp / 10000000);
tmp = tmp % 10000000;
sb.append(")-");
sb.apppend(tmp / 10000);
tmp = tmp % 10000000;
sb.append("-");
sb.append(tmp);
```

Comment: I doubt that is the **worst** - developers can be very creative [:-)

Answer (score 4):

You can implement your own method to do that for you, I recommend you to use something such as this. Using `DecimalFormat` and `MessageFormat`. With this method you can use pretty much whatever you want (`String,Integer,Float,Double`) and the output will be always right.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.MessageFormat;

/**
 * Created by Yamil Garcia Hernandez on 25/4/16.
 */

public class test {
    // Constants
    public static final DecimalFormat phoneFormatD = new DecimalFormat("0000000000");
    public static final MessageFormat phoneFormatM = new MessageFormat("({0}) {1}-{2}");

    // Example Method on a Main Class
    public static void main(String... args) {
        try {
            System.out.println(formatPhoneNumber("8091231234"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            System.out.println(formatPhoneNumber("18091231234"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            System.out.println(formatPhoneNumber("451231234"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            System.out.println(formatPhoneNumber("11231234"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            System.out.println(formatPhoneNumber("1231234"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            System.out.println(formatPhoneNumber("231234"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            System.out.println(formatPhoneNumber(""));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            System.out.println(formatPhoneNumber(0));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            System.out.println(formatPhoneNumber(8091231234f));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    // Magic
    public static String formatPhoneNumber(Object phone) throws Exception {

        double p = 0;

        if (phone instanceof String)
            p = Double.valueOf((String) phone);

        if (phone instanceof Integer)
            p = (Integer) phone;

        if (phone instanceof Float)
            p = (Float) phone;

        if (phone instanceof Double)
            p = (Double) phone;

        if (p == 0 || String.valueOf(p) == "" || String.valueOf(p).length() < 7)
            throw new Exception("Paramenter is no valid");

        String fot = phoneFormatD.format(p);

        String extra = fot.length() > 10 ? fot.substring(0, fot.length() - 10) : "";
        fot = fot.length() > 10 ? fot.substring(fot.length() - 10, fot.length()) : fot;

        String[] arr = {
                (fot.charAt(0) != '0') ? fot.substring(0, 3) : (fot.charAt(1) != '0') ? fot.substring(1, 3) : fot.substring(2, 3),
                fot.substring(3, 6),
                fot.substring(6)
        };
        String r = phoneFormatM.format(arr);
        r = (r.contains("(0)")) ? r.replace("(0) ", "") : r;
        r = (extra != "") ? ("+" + extra + " " + r) : r;
        return (r);
    }
}
```

Result will be

```
(809) 123-1234
+1 (809) 123-1234
(45) 123-1234
(1) 123-1234
123-1234
023-1234
java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
    at java.lang.Double.valueOf(Double.java:502)
    at test.formatPhoneNumber(test.java:66)
    at test.main(test.java:45)
java.lang.Exception: Paramenter is no valid
    at test.formatPhoneNumber(test.java:78)
    at test.main(test.java:50)
(809) 123-1232
```

Answer (score 2):

`DecimalFormat` doesn't allow arbitrary text *within* the number to be formatted, just as a prefix or a suffix. So it won't be able to help you there.

In my opinion, storing a phone number as a numeric value is wrong, entirely. What if I want to store an international number? Many countries use `+` to indicate a country code (e.g. `+1` for USA/Canda), others use `00` (e.g. `001`).

Both of those can't really be represented in a numeric data type ("Is that number 1555123 or 001555123?")

Comment: This should have rather been a comment rather than being a solution post, reason being it does not provide any possible solution, instead provides a remark/insight to the question asked. Well I could be wrong with my opinion.

Comment: I understand your concern, but sometimes the correct answer to questions like "How do I hammer in a nail if all I have is a loaded gun" is "don't do that".

Answer (score 2):

You could use the substring and concatenation for easy formatting too.

```
telephoneNumber = "("+telephoneNumber.substring(0, 3)+")-"+telephoneNumber.substring(3, 6)+"-"+telephoneNumber.substring(6, 10);
```

But one thing to note is that you must check for the lenght of the telephone number field just to make sure that your formatting is safe.

Answer (score 2):

U can format any string containing non numeric characters also to your desired format use my util class to format

### usage is very simple

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String num = "ab12345*&67890";

    System.out.println(PhoneNumberUtil.formateToPhoneNumber(num,"(XXX)-XXX-XXXX",10));
}
```

### output: (123)-456-7890

u can specify any foramt such as XXX-XXX-XXXX and length of the phone number , if input length is greater than specified length then string will be trimmed.

Get my class from here: https://github.com/gajeralalji/PhoneNumberUtil/blob/master/PhoneNumberUtil.java

Answer (score 2):

```
Pattern phoneNumber = Pattern.compile("(\\d{3})(\\d{3})(\\d{4})");
// ...
Matcher matcher = phoneNumber(numberAsLineOf10Symbols);
if (matcher.matches) {
    return "(" + matcher.group(1) + ")-" +matcher.group(2) + "-" + matcher.group(3);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd have thought you need to use a MessageFormat rather than DecimalFormat. That should be more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

String formatterPhone = String.format("%s-%s-%s", phoneNumber.substring(0, 3), phoneNumber.substring(3, 6), phoneNumber.substring(6, 10));

Comment: Can you add informations on what exactly that code does? A code only answer without explaining what it does is less useful. Also, format it so it appears as code.

Answer (score 0):

Using `StringBuilder` for performance.

```
long number = 12345678L;

System.out.println(getPhoneFormat(String.valueOf(number)));

public static String getPhoneFormat(String number)
{
    if (number == null || number.isEmpty() || number.length() < 6 || number.length() > 15)
    {
        return number;
    }

    return new StringBuilder("(").append(number.substring(0, 3))
            .append(") ").append(number.substring(3, 6))
            .append("-").append(number.substring(6))
            .toString();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin

```
val number = 088899998888

val phone = number.phoneFormatter()

fun String.phoneFormatter(): String { return this.replace("\\B(?=(\\d{4})+(?!\\d))".toRegex(), "-") }
```

The result will be  `0888-9999-8888`

Answer (score 0):

I used this one

String columValue = "1234567890

String number = columValue.replaceFirst("(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d+)", "($1) $2-$3");