# Format Phone Number Indentation using Java

Tags: java, arrays, string

If we have below two formats for phone number in string array.

YYYXXXZZZ , 
YYY-XXX-ZZZZ

and we want to normalize these phone numbers to :

XXX-YYY-ZZZZ.

How can we do it?

Comment: You want to normalize a 9 or 10 digit phone number into an 11 digit phone number? Where do those new digits come from? And you want to swap the X and Y blocks?

Comment: A similar question was answered [here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5114762/how-do-format-a-phone-number-as-a-string-in-java)

Comment: @Andy Sorry Mistake in Question let me fix it

Comment: @Andy yes on higher level we just want to Swap X and Y Blocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just extract the substrings based upon the detected format.

```
if (!p.contains("-")) {
  normalized = p.substring(3, 6) + "-" + p.substring(0, 3) + "-" + p.substring(6);
} else {
  normalized = p.substring(4, 7) + "-" + p.substring(0, 3) + "-" + p.substring(8);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you accidentally inserted an extra "Y" for your expected result.
**EDIT: It has been corrected**

```
public void formatNumber (String number) {
  String formatted=number.substring(3,6)+"-"+number.substring(0,3)+"-"+ number.substring(6);
  return formatted;
}
```