# How can I format int numbers in java?

Tags: java, string-formatting

I am trying to apply this format to a given int number `#´###,###` I tried with `DecimalFormat class` but it only allows to have one grouping separator symbol when I need to have two the `accute accent` for millions and commas for thousands.

So at the end I can format values like `1,000` or millions in this way `1´000,000`

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5114762/how-do-format-a-phone-number-as-a-string-in-java

Comment: @Roshan the solutions in that question make use of `substring()` or `replace()`, which might be OK for phone "numbers", but that isn't the best idea when dealing with actual numbers (like e.g. money). OP would need to take into account negative numbers, numbers without a decimal point, etc.

Comment: Thank you @Roshan!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found useful the link @Roshan provide in comments, this solution is using regex expression and replaceFirst method

```
public static String audienceFormat(int number) {
    String value = String.valueOf(number);

    if (value.length() > 6) {
            value = value.replaceFirst("(\\d{1,3})(\\d{3})(\\d{3})", "$1\u00B4$2,$3");
        } else if (value.length() >=5 && value.length() <= 6) {
            value = value.replaceFirst("(\\d{2,3})(\\d{3})", "$1,$2");
        }  else {
            value = value.replaceFirst("(\\d{1})(\\d+)", "$1,$2");
        }

    return value;
}
```

I don't know if this solution has a performance impact, also I am rockie with regex, so this code might be shorted.

Answer (score 1):

I always prefer to use String.format, but I am not sure if there is a Locale that would format numbers like that either. Here is some code that will do the job though.

```
// Not sure if you wanted to start with a number or a string. Adjust accordingly
String stringValue = "1000000";
float floatValue = Float.valueOf(stringValue);

// Format the string to a known format
String formattedValue = String.format(Locale.US, "%,.2f", floatValue);

// Split the string on the separator
String[] parts = formattedValue.split(",");

// Put the parts back together with the special separators
String specialFormattedString = "";
int partsRemaining = parts.length;
for(int i=0;i<parts.length;i++)
{
    specialFormattedString += parts[i];
    partsRemaining--;
    if(partsRemaining > 1)
        specialFormattedString += "`";
    else if(partsRemaining == 1)
        specialFormattedString += ",";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, these `Locale` formats in your required format.

```
    List<Locale> locales = Arrays.asList(new Locale("it", "CH"), new Locale("fr", "CH"), new Locale("de", "CH"));
    for (Locale locale : locales) {
        DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);
        DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = df.getDecimalFormatSymbols();
        dfs.setCurrencySymbol("");
        df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(dfs);
        System.out.println(String.format("%5s %15s %15s", locale, format(df.format(1000)), format(df.format(1_000_000))));
    }
```

util method

```
private static String format(String str) {
    int index = str.lastIndexOf('\'');
    if (index > 0) {
        return new StringBuilder(str).replace(index, index + 1, ",").toString();
    }
    return str;
}
```

output

```
it_CH        1,000.00    1'000,000.00
fr_CH        1,000.00    1'000,000.00
de_CH        1,000.00    1'000,000.00
```

set `df.setMaximumFractionDigits(0);` to remove the fractions

output

```
it_CH           1,000       1'000,000
fr_CH           1,000       1'000,000
de_CH           1,000       1'000,000
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try using this, the "#" in place with the units you want before the space or comma.

```
String num = "1000500000.574";
    String newnew = new   DecimalFormat("#,###.##").format(Double.parseDouble(number));
```

Comment: OP specifically said that DecimalFormat does not work.

Comment: Thanks @TiagoFutre but the format it does not work in my specific case