# Pebble template phone number format

Tags: template-engine, pebble

I wanted to format phone number which is passed as a string/number. I need to format that number to phone number like

Input to pebble template "5554781123". Output should be like "555.478.1123".

How do i format that number to phone number?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, whenever no function/filter is provided out of the box, in Pebble you can define your own function or filter (you can find more [here](http://www.mitchellbosecke.com/pebble/documentation/guide/extending-pebble) on how to extend Pebble by creating and registering functions, filters and tests).
So you can wrap [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5114914/1339429) into your own Pebble filter or function.