# String.format to add dots to Long/String

Tags: java, string, format, substring, string-formatting

I have the following Long: `201700112345`, and I want to convert it to `2017.001.12345`.

I know I could just use a substring:

```
long l = 201700112345L;
String s = Long.toString(l);
String result = s.substring(0,4)+"."+s.substring(4,7)+"."+s.substring(7);
```

But can I also accomplish this with a `String.format` EDIT: ..with a single input for the Object-varargs parameter of the `String.format` method?

Some things I've tried:

```
String.format("%4d.%3d.%5d", l);
// Which resulted in:
java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '%3d'
```

Which is quite obvious I realize, because I only have one input instead of three..

I know I can backtrack to the same input using `%1$`, so I then tried:

```
String.format("%4d.%1$3d.%1$5d", l);
// Which resulted in:
201700112345.201700112345.201700112345
```

I also tried this, which gave the correct lengths, but not the correct parts:

```
String.format("%.4s.%1$.3s.%1$.5s", Long.toString(l));
// Which resulted in:
2017.201.20170
```

I must admit I haven't used `String.format` all that often, so I'm not too sure if it's even possible to have some kind of substring as format. And if it is possible, I can't figure it out..

Comment: "can I also accomplish this with a String.format": `String.format("%s.%s.%s", s.substring(0, 4), s.substring(4, 7), s.substring(7))`.

Comment: maybe something like [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5114762/how-do-format-a-phone-number-as-a-string-in-java) can help you (just use dots instead of dashes..)

Comment: @AndyTurner Hehe, yeah, I know it's possible like that. ;) Edited my question.

Comment: @Nino Hmm, hadn't thought of using `.replaceAll`. That's also an alternative I guess: `Long.toString(l).replaceAll((.{4})(.{3})(.{5})", "$1.$2.$3"));`. Ah well, will just use `substring` I guess. I was just wondering if this can be accomplished with `String.format` at all, or if `String.format` hasn't anything for substrings in its arsenal.

Answer (score 1):

A more efficient way to do this than using `substring` is to use a `StringBuilder`: this has the [`append(CharSequence,int,int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append-java.lang.CharSequence-int-int-) method, which allows you to avoid unnecessarily creating substrings:

```
String formatted =
    new StringBuilder(s.length() + 2)
        .append(s, 0, 4)
        .append('.')
        .append(s, 4, 7)
        .append('.')
        .append(s, 7, s.length())
        .toString();
```