# How to format a String number into a US phone number format

Tags: java, android

I have an `EditText` and I want to format the whatever numbers are entered in the `EditText` into the US phone number format such as **1(123)123-123** so if the user enters the digit **1** automatically ( will be added this should work for deleting as well. I was able to add a text watcher and set up the logic but I am getting messed up during handling the deletion case.

Here is my code logic to format the first bracket but if we delete the bracket then it wont work

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public int after;
        public int before;

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            before = count;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            after = count;

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);
            if (before < after) {
                if (s.length() == 4 && s.charAt(0) == '1') {
                    String formated = "1 (" + s.toString().substring(1, 4) + ")";
                    editText.setText(formated);
                    editText.setSelection(editText.getText().toString().length());
                }
            }

            editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
        }
    });
```

Comment: One option here would just be to use three different boxes for the area code, exchange, and phone number.

Comment: You seem to be pretty new here, so here, please provide some of the code you are using already.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5114762/how-do-format-a-phone-number-as-a-string-in-java

Comment: @Qohelet I have added the code , please check it out and let me know if you can help me out

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use this functionality to check if the text was changed:

```
if (before < after)
```

Just given the case someone uses copy-paste to replace the phone number or marks one digit before replacing it.
Better save your text somewhere and if `!oldtext.equals(s.toString())` continue.

Assuming editText is your Textbox. Code is also untested, use at your own risk.

```
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);
                if (before < after) {
                    if (s.length() == 4 && s.charAt(0) == '1') {
                        long phoneFmt = Long.parseLong(s.toString().replaceAll("[^\\d]", ""),10);

DecimalFormat phoneDecimalFmt = new DecimalFormat("0000000000");
String phoneRawString= phoneDecimalFmt.format(phoneFmt);

java.text.MessageFormat phoneMsgFmt=new java.text.MessageFormat("({0})-{1}-{2}");
    //suposing a grouping of 3-3-4
String[] phoneNumArr={phoneRawString.substring(0, 3),
          phoneRawString.substring(3,6),
          phoneRawString.substring(6)};


                        editText.setText(phoneMsgFmt.format(phoneNumArr));
                        editText.setSelection(editText.getText().toString().length());
                    }
                }

                editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
            }
```