# How do I add - sign in printf

Tags: java, printf

so the last line of the code is currently

```
System.out.printf("%d%d%d%03d",Number1, Number2, Number3, Number4);
```

if I want a `-` sign in between the third number and the fourth number how do i do it? (like a phone number)

I tried to add it into the `%03d` or between `Number3, Number4`, it didnt work.

Comment: Insert a dash into your format string: `"%d%d%d-%03d"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do format a phone number as a String in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5114762/how-do-format-a-phone-number-as-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put `-`

```
System.out.printf("%d%d%d-%03d",Number1, Number2, Number3, Number4);
```

Comment: Got it, i put the - into the wrong place, thank you.

Comment: @Gold  [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) is what to do when someone answers your question. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark ✔ beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. There is no need to add a comment on your question or on an answer to say "Thank you".