# Dynamic formatting of phone number in cn1

Tags: codenameone

Are there any classes in cn1 similar to Android's `PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher` ?
I have a textfield for a phone number input. While user types in the phone number, I want it dynamically modify to "(123)456-7890" format. In general, this code will work https://stackoverflow.com/a/5114914/8921111 . But I need a real-time modifying.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can use a `DataChangeListener` and dynamically edit the input to force a specific mask but that isn't ideal...

A simpler solution would be to use separate text fields for each editable portion and move the input between those entries. You can automatically move the cursor between the fields when one is filled up. See the developer guide section that covers masking here: https://www.codenameone.com/developer-guide.html#_masking