# Mysql Bigint VS Varchar

Tags: mysql, sql

What is the best for index field, and space token on hard disk/RAM? Biginteger or Varchar(15) ?
I can have for example such index number:

```
from  10000001 to 45281229703 and higher...
```

But what is better to choose?
Also on non-indexing field what field type is better?

Comment: A better question is which type *correctly* represents the field .. once that is answered, use it. If there is no *measured* performance problem (with a setup that can also measure the performance of alternatives), then there is no performance problem - don't "optimize" like this.

Comment: @pst trouble is that bigint and varchar - both represent's the field normaly and so, how i need

Comment: No. One represents a number. The other represents text (which might be the textual representation of a number). Which is correct?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`BIGINT` is always 8 bytes, `VARCHAR(15)` is 1..16 bytes depending on value length, so `BIGINT` needs less memory on large numbers, but more memory on small numbers (shorter than 7 digits).  Also, BIGINT is faster.

Comment: but as foreign key in other table? for example: id text for_id, that for id i must do as bigint too, right? So what to choose? ) if i have from 1 to 45281229703 and higher row's

Comment: also unsigned/signed here is big difference?

Comment: Also remember that Varchar requires an encoding translation and is therefor ambiguous, a raw number does not have this problem.

Comment: oh, sorry my mistake, from 10000001 to 45281229703 is that big difference in types?

Comment: What’s your rationale for `BIGINT` being faster?

Comment: Always use `BIGINT` or other numeric data types if data is considered numeric value or can be cast

Answer (score 15):

We have run test in simulation environment.

1. Created able with 1 BIGINT and 1VARCHAR parameter.
2. Inserted 30Lac rows.
3. created index on both fields.
4. Result is : **BIGINT** respond almost **20time's** faster than VARCHAR.

Here is script to perform above steps:

```
Create table r5(mob bigint,m_mob varchar(30));

Create index i_d on r5(mob,m_mob);


do $$
begin
for i in 1..3000000 loop
insert into r5(mob,m_mob) values(i,i||’abc’);
end loop;
end; $$

select * from r5
where mob=2900000;

select * from r5
where m_mob=’2900000abc’;
```

Answer (score 4):

varchar adds overhead:

length of the string needs stored (extra 2 bytes IIRC in MySQL) per field and in the index
requires more processing for collation on comparison

Comment: but as foreign key in other table? for example: id text for_id, that for id i must do as bigint too, right?

Comment: also unsigned/signed here is big difference?

Comment: oh, sorry my mistake, from 10000001 to 45281229703 is that big difference in types?