# i want to convert from int64 to byte

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, ado.net

failed to convert parameter value from int32 to a byte
the database code

and the procedure in database is:

The webform code behind:

```
client c = new client();
c.name = Textbox_Addclient_first.Text + " " + Textbox_Addclient_second.Text + 
    " " + Textbox_Addclient_third.Text;
c.address = Textbox_addclientadress.Text;
c.phone = int.Parse(Textbox_addclientphone.Text);
```

The class code is:

```
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("add_client", con);

com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
com.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = this.name;
com.Parameters.Add("@address", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = this.address;
com.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.TinyInt).Value = this.phone;
com.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();

b = true;
```

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to convert a phone number to a byte...a byte array, perhaps. Why not change the type in your database instead? See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75105/what-datatype-should-be-used-for-storing-phone-numbers-in-sql-server-2005

Comment: In addition to the comment by @Rufus L (which is bang on, a byte stores from 0 to 255, that's not even big enough for a North American area code let alone a full phone number), phone numbers should never be stored in a numeric type. If you don't need to do math on it, don't store it as a number. It will give you nothing but grief in the long run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
com.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.TinyInt).Value = this.phone;
```

1. You are trying to pass the phone object to the name parameter.
2. You are using tinyint, varchar(10) would be a better option but if you insist on using integer, int64 should suffice.
3. If you are using int to make sure only digits are passed, do a regular expression check on the string for digits using "[0-9]{10}"