# Entering Phone Number in SQL, losing leading zero

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL and I need to enter mobile phone numbers into a table, for example, 0425 198 053. I can enter the data, but how do I display as it is entered? I have used `INT`, `VARCHAR` and `CHAR` but all entries with those constraints drop the 0 off the phone number when it is displayed.

Is there a particular constraint I should use and is it a formatting issue?

**Edited to add**

This is the table I have been using

```
CREATE TABLE Department
(
    dID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    dName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Address VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Phone VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
)
```

Example data

```
dID  dName       Address    Phone
--------------------------------------
1    Sales       CBD        425198053
2    Accounts    Bundoora   429198955
3    Admin       CBD        428198758
4    Marketing   Clayton    427198757
```

Comment: `but all entries with those constraints drop the 0 off the phone number` ... a varchar column certainly would preserve a leading zero.  Maybe you should tell us how you are displaying this data.

Comment: Is there a way to keep the 0 form dropping off?

Comment: It would help people to help you if you provide a [mcve]. As it says on that page, if you try creating one you will probably find your own problem. I would say that is definitely the case here. VarChar would be fine but you're obviously mishandling the data somewhere.

Comment: dID dName Address Phone
1 Sales CBD         425198053
2 Accounts Bundoora 429198955
3 Admin CBD         428198758
4 Marketing Clayton         427198757

Comment: This is the Query I have been using                                                         
CREATE TABLE Department(
dID INT PRIMARY KEY,
dName VARCHAR (20)NOT NULL,
Address VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
Phone VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
);

Comment: Also, when you need to add significant information to your question, please [edit] the question rather than add it in comments. I will do that for you, then you can delete those comments.

Comment: You need to show us how that value is getting into the database and onto the screen. I would love to help, but your question isn't even tagged with the brand of SQL that you're using, let alone any details of the application where the problem is occurring.

Comment: @Strato . . . The issue is either your `insert` statements or how you are using the results from the `select`.  `varchar()` is the correct type, but you haven't provided the information needed to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

I just stuck with the VARCHAR (10). It still provides a solution, I was just wondering how to get it to display with a zero. 
Thanks anyway.

Comment: We're all just wondering how you are displaying it.. and putting the data in there. I'm curious as to why you are completely uninterested in furnishing this information.

Comment: Agree with Nick and Gordon, I'd like to help you find the solution to this problem, but you haven't given us enough information. My guess would be that somewhere, something is treating it as one of the numeric types rather than one of the string types.

Answer (score -1):

this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75105/what-datatype-should-be-used-for-storing-phone-numbers-in-sql-server-2005/17784147) was written in 2008 and still is relevant:

> Does this include:
>
> - International numbers?
> - Extensions?
> - Other information besides the actual number (like "ask for bobby")?
>
> If all of these are no, I would use a 10 char field and strip out all
>   non-numeric data. If the first is a yes and the other two are no, I'd
>   use two varchar(50) fields, one for the original input and one with
>   all non-numeric data striped and used for indexing. If 2 or 3 are yes,
>   I think I'd do two fields and some kind of crazy parser to determine
>   what is extension or other data and deal with it appropriately. Of
>   course you could avoid the 2nd column by doing something with the
>   index where it strips out the extra characters when creating the
>   index, but I'd just make a second column and probably do the stripping
>   of characters with a trigger.
>
> Update: to address the AJAX issue, it may not be as bad as you think.
>   If this is realistically the main way anything is done to the table,
>   store only the digits in a secondary column as I said, and then make
>   the index for that column the clustered one.

Meaning, long story short, the best way to save a phone number in sql, is a **10 char field** or a **varchar(50) field**.

You can also create a trigger (if you are up to dealing with triggers) in order to strip any unwanted chars in the phone number value.

Take in consideration that the trigger can get messy when starting to deal with code as well but, it's your decision from here.

Comment: *"this one was written in 2008"* - Please can you link the source?

Comment: added as requested :)

Comment: Thanks, because 10 digits isn't long enough for any of my phone numbers, so I added a comment there; and in fact that was mentioned in the next most upvoted answer on that question.

Comment: On a separate note, *this* answer does not address the OPs problem of losing the leading zero.

Comment: That's true, it addresses the one part of the issue, the second can be done by the trigger on the side note.

Comment: *"the trigger on the side note"* - do you mean the *"You can also create a trigger...in order to strip any unwanted chars"* part? The OP isn't looking to strip anything else off; they have already unintentionally lost the leading zero, which is the problem.

Comment: And anyway, the OP has stated that the column is `Phone VARCHAR (10)`.

Comment: or you can do it the other way around, to make sure you didn't lose the leading zero. This is not a fixed functionality here.