# Converting bigint to smallint shows an error

Tags: sql-server

```
ALTER TABLE employee 
ALTER COLUMN emp_phoneNo SMALLINT;
```

I am trying to alter the data type from `BIGINT` to `SMALLINT` and it is showing this error:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.

I am not able to understand what is wrong.

Comment: What about the error don't you understand? The error is quite clear, and the maximum/minimum values of a `smallint` vs a `bigint` is huge (`-32,768` to `32,767` vs `-9,223,372,036,854,775,808` to `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`). It cannot really be more clear. You have a value that's too large/small for a `smallint`.

Comment: How about to keep it as it is.

Comment: You have to consider the magnitude of each type as @Larnu has said. It sounds like getting passengers from a full bus and put them into a car.

But, to be helpful, and CONSIDERING the related values already populated FITS in smallint, try to create a new field smallint, execute a SQL query to update this field:

update [table] 
  set [new_smallint_field] = cast([bigint_field] as smallint)

IMPORTANT! This maybe causes integrity issues in your database. 

Good luck!

Comment: Which means there are some records which are greater than Max value of SMALLINT. So it throws Arthimetic Overflow Exception.Please Check the data once

Comment: thanks for all your replies. i understood my silly mistake . thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have existing rows with values in that specific column that are bigger than the new data type allows.

You need to update or delete the rows that are currently "oversized".

(or not perform the column alter at all .. because most likely you don't want to lose the information)

You can find the rows with this query:

> SELECT 'CurrentlyOverSized' as MyLabel,  * FROM dbo.employee WHERE ABS(emp_phoneNo ) > 32767

Note a phone number like : 5555555555 (which would be numeric for 555-555-5555) would be greater than the 32767 number.

Even 5555555 (for 555-5555 (no area code)) is too big for 32767.

Also

A debatable topic.  But number or string for storing phone numbers...check out this link for food for thought:

[What datatype should be used for storing phone numbers in SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75105/what-datatype-should-be-used-for-storing-phone-numbers-in-sql-server-2005)

Personally I think numeric is the wrong data type for phone numbers.

Whatever you do, be consistent.  If you go with a string (varchar(xyz)) for example..........store them with no extra characters 5555555555, with hyphens 555-555-5555 , with dot 555.555.5555  .. or whatever but do them all the same would be my advice.

Comment: No numerical data type is correct for a phone number. Many countries use leading zeroes for phone number; something you cannot store in any of the numerical data types.

Comment: Personally I agree.  But some do not.. Thus why I labeled it a debatable topic.  As you say, if you need leading zeros, its the wrong data type.  But some only want usa phone numbers.  Thus the caveats and some debate.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @granadaCoder. I understood my mistake . It looks very silly now. But, Thanks again.